# Error thrown after SaveBinary in ItemAdded event handler

Tags: document-library, event-handlers, spfile

I'm working on a ItemAdded event for a document library, and I'm running into this error in SharePoint 2007...

The file Lists/Shared Audit Documents/1387/Audit Report.docm has been modified by msclistmembershipprovider:afitzpatrick@t on 27 Apr 2012 11:19:31 -0400. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The
>   file Lists/Shared Audit Documents/1387/Audit Report.docm has been
>   modified by msclistmembershipprovider:afitzpatrick@t on 27 Apr 2012
>   11:19:31 -0400.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [COMException (0x81020037): The file Lists/Shared Audit
>   Documents/1387/Audit Report.docm has been modified by
>   msclistmembershipprovider:afitzpatrick@t on 27 Apr 2012 11:19:31
>   -0400.]    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID,
>   String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String
>   bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object&
>   pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut,
>   Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String&
>   pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String
>   bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object&
>   pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut,
>   Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish) +203
>
> [SPException: The file Lists/Shared Audit Documents/1387/Audit
>   Report.docm has been modified by
>   msclistmembershipprovider:afitzpatrick@t on 27 Apr 2012 11:19:31
>   -0400.]    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String&
>   pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String
>   bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object&
>   pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut,
>   Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish) +251
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean
>   bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean
>   bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin,
>   Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object&
>   objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents) +1026
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents) +182
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion() +94
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.SaveItem(SPContext
>   itemContext, Boolean uploadMode, String checkInComment) +215
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.SaveItem() +71
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +277
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>   +37    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +166
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +175    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

I basically am taking an uploaded macro-enabled document, copying all the data to a clean template, then using SaveBinary.  Code is as follows...

```
    private void UploadFile(string strNewPath, SPListItem spliItem, Guid gSiteID)
    {
        //string strSiteURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSCMail.NewUserLink"];
        string DocumentFileURL = spliItem.Web.Url + '/' + spliItem.Url;

        FileStream fileStream = null;
        Byte[] fileContent = null;
        fileStream = File.OpenRead(strNewPath);
        fileContent = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length)];
        fileStream.Read(fileContent, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
        fileStream.Close();

        SPSite spsMySite = new SPSite(gSiteID);
        SPFile tempFile = spliItem.File;

        spsMySite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        this.DisableEventFiring();

        tempFile.SaveBinary(fileContent);
        this.EnableEventFiring();

        spsMySite.Dispose();
    }
```

I hit the error when I click OK on the editform.aspx for the Document Library.  Now, I've researched this a bit on the web, and I could move code to a later event, such as ItemUpdated or ItemCheckedIn.  There's a couple of other suggestions here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manuj/archive/2009/09/22/itemadded-event-on-document-library-the-file-has-been-modified-by-on-error.aspx

Any recommendations on the best way to get around this error?